# Flutter: Best way to synchronise contacts

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to build a whatsapp clone (just for fun).

The problem I'm facing is, I'm not able to decide what approach should I take for building the sync contacts feature for the app.

What is this feature about?
The user must be able to see/search all his contacts who have registered on my app.

My approach:
Currently, what I'm doing is:
On fresh install, I take all the contacts in the phonebook of the user, then I query the server if the particular contact has an account. Then, I flag the account as a user. This process happens for all the contacts in the phone book(No wonder, it took me almost 5 minutes to sync 600 contacts).
I take all these contacts and their results and store it in a sqlite database, so that the next time, user tries to search for a contact, he gets the result immediately.

Is there a better approach, and I found that Android SDK has a ContactsProvider which is quite powerful since I can query for accounts by type, but I also found out, I have to use AccountManager so that I can add an account on the devices. Then I discovered, I would have to implement SyncAdapter to sync the contacts betwen client and the server.

Interestingly, all these 3 frameworks/APIs, do not have flutter plugins developed yet.

Curious to know if there are other options too?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am looking for something similar.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this?